# PHP File Upload Help

Tags: php, html, forms, file, upload

```
<html><head><title>File Upload</title></head>
<body bgcolor = "lavender"><div align = "center">
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && move_uploaded_file(
$_FILES['file']['name']))
{
echo "<font color = 'green'>The file has been uploaded.</font>";
}
else echo "<font color = 'red'>There was an error uploading the file.</font>";
?>
</div></body>
</html>
```

This is my code.
I am trying to upload a file via a seperate form in a seperate webpage, using the method 'get'. 
The code to the form as shown is here:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "fileupload.php" method = "get">
<input type = "file" name = "file"><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Upload">
</form>
```

For some reason I keep on getting the error message - although I'm pretty sure I'm doing it right. This is my first time doing this, suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

it should be tmp_name

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'ftp/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))
```

and do not send it as GET

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "fileupload.php" method = "post">
```

(changed get to post)

Comment: I would also advise validating the file too with your PHP, check file type, size etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you would need to supply a destination in the [move-uploaded-file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function as an argument. If the move to the destination (in this case non-existent) cannot be accomplished, it would return false, which is why it would go to your else{} condition.

Comment: For some reason, my code got cut off. It should be                   if (isset($_FILES['file']) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'ftp/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))

Comment: In that case, check the permissions of that folder and if the file is actually being moved there.

Comment: What would the permissions have to be? And no, it isn't being moved.

Comment: Make sure that the directory exists (that would be step one, and that you have write permissions on that directory - chmod 755 would be sufficient). Also, see the other response about method="get" that it should be "post".

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded_file() requires a `$destination` parameter as it's second argument. This should be set to the path at which you want to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send the file through $_GET. You should use POST as your method for the form.