# PHP File Upload Help

Tags: php, html, forms, file, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP File Upload Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375565/php-file-upload-help)

```
<html><head><title>File Upload</title></head>
<body bgcolor = "lavender"><div align = "center">
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'],'ftp/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))
{
echo "<font color = 'green'>The file has been uploaded.</font>";
}
else echo "<font color = 'red'>There was an error uploading the file.</font>";
?>
</div></body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I am trying to upload a file via a seperate form in a seperate  webpage, using the method 'get'. The code to the form as shown is here:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "fileupload.php" method = "get">
<input type = "file" name = "file"><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Upload">
</form>
```

For some reason I keep on getting the error message - although I'm pretty sure I'm doing it right. This is my first time doing this, suggestions would be appreciated.